# Change Data Type of existing Tiff tag using LibTiff.Net

Tags: tiff, libtiff, libtiff.net

I'm using the latest version of LibTiff.Net to fix some tiffs to be included in X9.37 files. I have got all the correct tags down, however, there are a couple of them that are DataType 'short' when I need them to be 'long'. Is there a best way to change just the datatype? Or will I have to create a custom tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to at least rewrite each directory in your TIFFs. But please make sure the library writes relevant tags with the data type you need (or change the source code of the library if it doesn't).

In case X9.37 files (I don't know what it is) require TIFF directory to be placed in certain places of the file, you might be forced to recreate the file completely (by copying tags and raw raster).

Comment: The definition of ImageWidth and ImageLength say they can be either SHORT or LONG. Is there any benefit or advantage to having them as LONG *if* the dimensions are going to be small? Does the library know which type to use and automatically set the type to LONG if the values are large enough that it needs it? If so, I may not have to change anything. I was just afraid that the library will write those tags only as SHORT.